# R package NAMESPACE

Tags: r, namespaces, package, documentation, drc

I am documenting an R function. The structure of my R file is as below:

```
#'Report the modeling result
#'
#' @param higher_rank A string.
#' @param lower_rank A string.
#' @param method A string.
#' @return modeling result of the accumulation of \code{lower_rank} of a \code{higher_rank} by \code{method}
#' @import data.table
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import drc drm
#' @importFrom plotly ggplotly
#'@examples
#'\dontrun{
#'modelit("adult", "child", "logistic")
#'}
#'@export

modelit <- function(higher_rank, lower_rank, method) {

...
...

model.drm <- drc::drm(lower_rank ~ higher_rank, data = data.frame(adults = adults, children = children), fct = MM.2())

...
...
```

}

As I ran

```
>devtools::document()
```

An error pops up:

```
Warning messages:
1: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
there is no package called ‘drm’
2: character(0) 
3: character(0) 
4: In loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
there is no package called ‘drm’
```

As I do not have a package drm but drc, I am curious where this warning comes from. In NAMESPACE, I do see

```
importFrom(drm,drc)
```

I highly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the tag `@import` instead of `@importFrom`. Thus, you asked for importing the package `drm`instead of the function `drm` from `drc`

Btw, you don't need any import tag for `drm` since you called the function by namespace `drc::drm`

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. However, I still have `Warning messages:
1: character(0) 
2: character(0) `

Comment: I can tall the other warning messages come from `#' @importFrom plotly ggplotly` as I do not use this package/function in my code. Now the problem is solved.